# Как обойти конфилкт модели simple history поле instance, c моей моделью с полем instance?

Tags: django, history

Я использую для отслеживание событии simple-history, и она создает историческии модели указанных мной моделей,у меня в модели есть поле instance, в документации simple-history говориться что поле instance:

Поскольку эти поля и методы присутствуют во всех исторических моделях, любые имена полей или методов на базовой модели, которые конфликтуют с этими именами, не будут на исторической модели (и, таким образом, отслеживаться не будут). Зарезервированные исторические поля и имена методов приведены ниже:

```
history_id
history_date
history_change_reason
history_type
history_object
history_user
history_user_id
instance
instance_type
next_record
prev_record
revert_url
__str__
```

как мне это обойти?

Comment: вопрос не вполне понятен. попробуйте описать более подробно, желательно с минимально воспроизводимым примером

Comment: class Position(BaseRefMixin):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Position')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Positions')

    org_unit = models.ForeignKey(OrgUnit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_code = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    instance = models.ForeignKey(SystemInstance, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)  у меня есть такой класс модели, в нем есть поле instance. при создание исторической модели Position, у меня теперь при создание позиции выпадает ошибка HistoricalPosition() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance_id'

Comment: документации говориться что нельзя использовать название поле instance. я пробовал сделать через property  def _get_instance(self):
        return self.instance

    instance_test = property(_get_instance)
это не помогло

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev 
class Position(BaseRefMixin): class Meta: verbose_name = _('Position') verbose_name_plural = _('Positions') org_unit = models.ForeignKey(OrgUnit, on_delete=models.CASCADE) full_code = models.TextField(default='', blank=True) instance = models.ForeignKey(SystemInstance, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True) у меня есть такой класс модели, в нем есть поле instance. при создание исторической модели Position, у меня теперь при создание позиции выпадает ошибка HistoricalPosition() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance_id'

Comment: Исправьте вопрос и допишите классы туда. В комментариях это нечитаемо